# Blank White Screen when deploying to Android from Worklight; iOS works normal

Tags: android, webview, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Jquery mobile app that loads one view on a `changePage` event inside of a `webview` and then loads another view when input is received from the user and a button is clicked. The first `changePage` event loads fine. However, the second `changePage` event does not show any content. The screen changes only to a blank, white screen.

This issue only appears on Android 2.3 +. I have enabled hardware acceleration. The weird thing is that the first view (a login view) works fine. It only occurs when I do a second change page event. This app works great in a standard browser and also works good on the iPhone. I get the same issue when using an Android emulator.

My Worklight version is: 6.1.0.00.20131219-1900. I am able to port this app to iOS 7 and below. It just is not working completely on any Android device that I test with.

Anybody have any idea on what needs to be tweaked to get this web app to continually load in a web view? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include your Worklight project for further investigation. You can upload it to dropbox or some similar service. It would help to allow better problem determination on my end

Comment: Agreed with the above comment. This is too theoretical. Either add your project or create a demo project that recreates it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add the project to a public repository for proprietary reasons. Idan, I have talked with you before on other Worklight situations. Please check your Lotus Notes for a direct download link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After receiving your project and doing some investigation I believe I have found the cause of this issue. Inside of your application you make a call to a load a specific view (normal view in your case) in a changePage event after an event is triggered (a button click). The problem is that when you referenced the view in your code it did not match the correct name of the view you were attempting to load. Please make sure when referencing these files you have the correct spelling and correct case structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I didn't think that upper/lower case letters would make a difference on changePage events. I appreciate the help